# Git merge strategy for integrating 'patch' branch into 'minor', 'minor' branch into 'major'

Tags: git

We have a repository containing a number of Java projects (~20 or so) built by Maven.

We have 3 branches in our repository, `patch`, `minor`, and `major`.

For `ProjectA`, the `pom.xml` and `MANIFEST.MF` on the `patch` branches are set to `1.3.7`, while on `minor` they're set to `1.4.0`, and on `major` they're set to `2.0.0`.

Here's the pain point: *When performing a release* from the `patch` branch, we then want to merge that new tag (`projecta-1.3.7`) forward into the `minor` and `major` branches.

The issue, is that even if we've only changed one `.java` file on the patch branch (say it was a critical bugfix), **every time** we have to go through and resolve the conflicts for every one of the `pom.xml` and `MANIFEST.MF` files. So this:

```
git checkout minor
git merge projecta-1.3.7
```

Results in `minor` getting the bugfix (woo hoo!) but then **also** requires us to go through and compare the conflict between all the `projecta-1.3.7` projects using patch versions, and the `minor` projects using minor versions.

Is there a way to tell Git, **as part of the merge command**, that we want to use the 'ours' strategy for both `pom.xml, MANIFEST.MF`, but that any other conflicts should be resolved using the default strategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually handle this by committing the code changes for the bug fix as a separate commit(s) from the commit to bump up the version # (which I assume is the change to the pom.xml and MANIFEST files).  I can then merge the code change commits into the other branches normally and then lastly "fake" merge the "version # bump" change separately with `merge --strategy=ours`.

---

Op asks:

> Our process is: (1) release project 1.3.7 (2) merge the tag into future branches ('minor') (3) update POM/MANIFEST to 1.3.8, (4) ...work... (5) then, a couple weeks later, start back at (1) again.

Okay, my flow was a little different, but following your flow, if step 3 generated commit #1234ABCD, then I would additional do step 3a:

```
$ git checkout MAINLINE
$ git merge --strategy=ours 1234ABCD
```

This will ensure that when you loop back arond and hit step #2 in the future, the version # bump will have been considered merged and be ignored.

Alternatively, don't do 3a until later.  When you reach step #2 in the future, then do the fake merge of #1234ABCD and then merge all the commits on the branch after #1234ABCD. When you bump the version # in the branch again - "fake merge" it (immediately or later).

The core idea is just to isolate the commit the bumps the version # and "fake" merge it separately - when you do that is up to you. Even if the version # bump is in the middle of the commits on the branch you want to merge, then merge all the other commits before the one that one first, then fake merge the one that bumps the version #, then merge all the commits after that one.

---

Here's a rough pic of a merge I did last week.  Commits down the left margin are MAINLINE development, the ones not on the left margin where made in the RELEASEBRANCH (maintenance branch). The commit order doesn't match your flow, but that doesn't matter.

```
*   bc26f91 Oct 31 Fake merge from IT17p2 to ignore inapplicable commit: All web-apps: blah blah blah (MAINLINE)
|\
| * 3cd69ad Oct 31 All web-apps: bump release # for new release (RELEASEBRANCH)
* |   8eae339 Oct 31 Merge fix from IT17p2: All web-apps: blah blah blah
|\ \
| |/
| * 3612072 Oct 31 All web-apps: blah blah blah
| |
```

Comment: Our process is: (1) release project 1.3.7 (2) merge the tag into future branches ('minor') (3) update POM/MANIFEST to 1.3.8, (4) ...work... (5) then, a couple weeks later, start back at (1) again. Our step (3) *is* a separate commit. But how do you "merge the code change commits into the other branches", without getting that version change commit? Do you merge the revision range?

Comment: My example is fairly easy, with maybe a single change. But if there are maybe 20-30 commits on a minor release that need to be merged into `major`, that's where it gets more complex. I could see finding the commit immediately *after* the version change, and merging `thatrev+1..`, but that still involves *finding* the commit ref.