# Alternatives of migrating commits from one branch to another in GIT

Tags: git, python-2.7

I am currently working on a python project using GIT and we have two branches master and release. New features are committed to the master branch while bug fixes alone are made to the release branch.

My question is what would be the best way to have the bug fixes migrated to the master branch from the release branch.

Two ways I can think of were to do a rebase but this has never really worked well for me. The other method I thought of was to do cherrypicks but this will be tedious. A colleague of mine told me that I can could change the origin of the master branch to some other point but I do not really know what he meant by this.

I would like to know what alternatives are available and what is the current best practise/sure fire way of doing this. I would appreciate it if you could also post the commands or point me to some examples.

Thanks in advance,
nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Normally you would simply merge the release branch into the development branch.**

In a typical workflow, the release branch is branched off from the development branch.  As you described, new development commits are added to the development branch and hotfixes are added to the release branch. At some point, you would then have the development branch merge in the release branch, i.e. the development branch gets a new merge commit and the development branch head (master) advances while the release branch head stays put untouched.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge -m "Merge in hotfix for 'blah blah blah' back into develop" release
```

The development branch will now contain both the new development commits and the hotfixes, while release branch still contains just the hotfixes.  You can continue to add additional hotfixes to the release branch and have development merge them in (as well as continue to commit development work to the development branch).

The gitflow picture has a visualization of this:

- http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

This approach doesn't let you select which hotfixes get merged back to develop (unless you do something specifically to exclude certain commits).  Remember that when one branch merges in another, the first branch effectively get all the commits from the second branch (from the merge point of the second branch back) that the first branch didn't already have, i.e.  it gets all commits made on the release branch after it broke off from develop that hadn't been previously already merged into develop. If you made 2 hotfixes on the release, didn't merge the first, but then choose to have development merge in the tip of the release branch after the 2nd hotfix, development will have get both hotfixes.

--

The only hotfixes changes that you may not want in the development branch are changes like bumping the version #.  You'll either need to fix that during the merge (or after) or else make sure you isolate those changes in a separate commit in the release branch so that you can "fake" merge that commit separately back into the development branch, i.e. make the development branch think it already has that commit without actually incorporating the "diffs" of that commit. I roughly described the process here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19794987/11296

For example, if you do a bugfix on release branch and then update the version # in the docs/code in a separate commit (the last commit), then merge that into the development branch like this:

```
$ git checkout release
$ <implement bugfix>
$ git add ...
$ git commit -m "bugfix for ..."
$ <change the version #>
$ git commit -m "bump version number to ..."

$ # Ready to pull this bugfix into development
$ git checkout master
$ # Merge in the bugfix changes (i.e. all but the last commit)
$ git merge -m "Merge in hotfix for 'blah blah blah' back into develop" release^
$ # "Fake" merge the version # change
$ git merge --strategy=ours -m "Fake merge version # change" release
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer I think I have a clearer picture now about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a rebase is essentially doing a bunch of cherry-picks in a row - that's what the rebase script calls under the hood.

If I understand you, there may or may not be some common ancestor point, R, where master and release were identical. Subsequently, features and fixes have been added to master, while only critical fixes were added to release:

```
R <- feat <- feat <- fix <- feat <- fix <- feat [master]
 \
  \
   <- fix <- fix <- fix [release]
```

If this is the case, you want to rebase MOST of the release branch onto master (there may be "panic fixes" that you made to address a production problem, but you don't want to keep).

Rebase is the way to go for this. Look at the git book chapter on rebasing, and keep reading it until you get what it's telling you. (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

In particular, you want to be aware of automatic rebasing AND interactive rebasing. Using interactive rebase gives you the chance to "drop" changes that you don't want to move over. That is the solution for the "panic fix" problem.

Comment: Thanks I will have to try rebase again probably on a fresh clone and see if I can make it work.